# "SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol" After server upgrade

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

Recently we build new Windows 2012 server, with tomcat 7.0.57 and java version "1.8.0_45".

I am getting below error, when connecting from a client openssl. But working perfectly from IE.

New server:

```
OpenSSL> s_client -connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(00000130)
5724:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:.\ssl\s
23_clnt.c:601:
OpenSSL>
```

Old server: (connecting fine)

```
OpenSSL> s_client -connect yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:443
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(00000114)
depth=1 /C=XX/O=YYYY CA1
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
.........
SSL handshake has read 3064 bytes and written 282 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
Cipher    : EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
.......
```

Can any one tell why behaving like this??

New Server:
Windows 2012 R2 / java version "1.8.0_45"/ Tomcat 7.0.57

Old Server:
Windows 2003 / java version "1.6.0_31"/ Tomcat 6.0

Client:
Windows 7 / Java 1.7.0_75

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Java 1.8 and Tomcat [7.0.57 and later](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html) disable `SSLv3` by default, Java 1.8 disabled `SSLv2Hello` by default, and OpenSSL uses `SSLv2Hello` and `SSLv3` by default, so there is a protocol mismatch and the two sides can't properly complete the SSL/TLS handshake.

If you want to connect from OpenSSL `s_client`, use the `-tls1` switch (or `-tls1_1`, etc.) and you should be able to connect.

If you want to re-enable `SSLv3` in Tomcat, read the [Configuration section of the Tomcat Users' Guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support), specifically about the `sslEnabledProtocols` and `sslProtocol` attributes.

**EDIT 2015-10-19 16:40 America/New_York**

The above applies to Java-based connectors, which use the JVM's built-in JSSE for cryptography. If you use the native APR-base connector, OpenSSL will be used. The default behavior of OpenSSL will depend upon the version you have installed... as more recent versions have been released, the default protocols have been revised.

You can always use Tomcat's configuration to enable any protocol, as long as the underlying library (JSSE or OpenSSL) supports the protocol.

OpenSSL will use the exact protocol-specific handshake if you pick a single supported protocol (e.g. `TLSv1` -> TLSv1 handshake, `TLSv1.1` -> TLSv1.1 handshake, etc.) but will use `SSLv2hello` if you have more than one protocol enabled (e.g. `SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1"`). This is documented under the `SSLProtocol` attribute for [Tomcat's HTTP connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_APR/Native).

If you are unsure, be very specific with your enabled protocols (regardless of connector type), and always test with a reputable test suite to determine which protocols are being properly-supported.

Comment: Assuming JSSE (not "native"=APR) Java 8 or 7 JSSE by default disables SSLv2Hello on *client* but not *server*; per your link Tomcat apparently does disable it.
OpenSSL *commandline* `s_client` defaults to v2 format through 0.9.8, v3 from 1.0.0 up; source info in OP's error message indicates he is running 0.9.8 patch j through l from 2009.
0.9.8 and 1.0.0 don't implement TLS1.1 or 1.2 and thus has no `-tls1_1` flag, nor `-tls1_2` nor the `-no_` versions. 
...

Comment: ... All versions by default *offer* at least 1.0 even in v2 format (1.0.1 and up offer 1.2) but JSSE 8 with SSLv2Hello off rejects any v2 offer,
using alert 40 with version 1.2 (thus v3 format) that 0.9.8 client treats as invalid. Intriguingly, JSSE **7** alerts with version 1.0, which OpenSSL understands, but even so 40=handshake_failure isn't terribly helpful.
(OpenSSL *library* doesn't default at all, it's up to the app.) Those said, I concur in the conclusion.

Comment: openssl command worked with -tls (s_client -connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 -tls). But when i tried to enable SSlv3 in tomcat server itself by setting sslProtocol="SSLv3", openssl command is not working (without -tls).  As per my understanding. If we enable SSLv3 in server, openssl should work without -tls..